# Intellij idea - choose schema warning, how to get rid of it?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've added datasource to the page ( that has users table ) and then this happened.

[image]

It is not a compilation error, just a warning from idea, but what can I do to get rid of it?
When I click 'Choose schema' nothing happens.

Comment: May you show the database properties and structure in the databases tool window? Does the IDE see the schema of this database?

Answer (score 3):

Set your project SQL Dialect: Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> SQL Dialects

[SQL Dialects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJEpq.png)

Set your SQL Resolution Scope to point to your schema: Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> SQL Resolution Scopes

[SQL Resolution Scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv6eq.png)

You might have to manually add the path of your project and schema if the dropdown is not populated